# Convert \MongoDB\Driver\Manager to \MongoDB without reinitializing connection

Tags: php, mongodb

Does anyone know how to convert an instance of `\MongoDB\Driver\Manager` into an instance of `\MongoDB` without reinitializing connection or at least is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

\MongoDB\Driver\Manager is the main entry point. you create one, store it in $var and call methods on it when you need:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
```

then when you need to query the db you do 
$manager-> .. whatever 
for example

```
$manager->executeQuery('db.collection', $query);
```

This is the only thing that you can do with that and nothing else.
If you use the same $manager value you use the same connection.